# Set DATE attribute to default to some fixed date

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Trying to create a table that has DATE attribute `release`.

I want to default this date to some fixed date (specifically `9999-12-31`) but I get an SQL syntax error using the following method:

```
CREATE TABLE price(
    ...
    release DATE DEFAULT '99991231',
    ...
);
```

The little searching I've done has only shown me how to default to current date or some form of a dynamic date but I'm just looking for a way to default to a fixed date.

**EDIT** more detail:

```
CREATE TABLE game(gid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
               name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
               release DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
               platform VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
               released BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
               PRIMARY KEY(gid)
              );
```

I get the following error after issuing the command: `mysql -u root -p trade < game.sql`

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',
               platform VARCHAR(' at line 3
```

where trade is the name of an empty database and `mysql --version` yields the output `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: this works --  `release` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31',

Comment: @BerndBuffen hmmm, that's not working for me either for some reason(same error) editing post with more details...

Comment: sorry, i see it. In the comments you cant see Backticks. You must put the feldname in backticks. release is a keyword. so if you want to use it as fieldname you must quote it with backticks

Comment: @BerndBuffen thank you. I was not aware release was a keyword! I ended up changing it to `release_date` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample with  backticks:

```
CREATE TABLE `r` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `release` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-01-01',
  `comment` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1234567892 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: interesting you used back ticks on all attributes... is this standard practice? and if yo don't mind, what is the reasoning behind the `ENGINE=...` blurb at the end?

Comment: first you can choise the engine type MyISAM, InnoDB,... , the start id of the autoincrement field and the used charset. Normaly auto_increment is 1, but i copied from an old table with many rows